# Predicting stock returns using principal components of macroeconomic variables

Tags: returns, forecasting, pca, prediction, principal-components

I'm trying to detect return predictability by regressing stock returns on the first couple of principal components of a set of macroeconomic variables. I'm doing this for different stock styles such as small, value and momentum stocks. Since I don't know at which lag I should insert these principal components, I'm hoping to find someone who can help me out.

[image]

Later on I would use these principal components in another regression that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should first implement an automatic selection algorithm which starts with a lot of possible lags then gradually removes them by performing new regressions. It stops as soon as all your coefficients are statistically significant. Let data talk.